# Send messages to bot users in microsoft teams via api

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an use case where i have to trigger notifications with card, message and url to bot users when an event has occured at backend. Is there a way to send message to bot users via api

Comment: Do you want to send specific users a message or just post a message in a channel?

Comment: I want to send personal messages to users and also show notifications.

Comment: Currently APIs to send 1:1 message are not available. To send notification in personal scope you can use [Proactive messaging for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive), To alert user in [activity feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed#rest-api-sample) please set notification alert to true.

Comment: Thanks.. I can also see proactive messaging is only option left. I was exploring that if any other option available then it would have been more helpful.